# Getting error while connecting to the database[SOAP UI]

Tags: soapui

I have placed the mariadb driver in the SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory. It says says no such property: sql for class

This is the code I tried:

```
//Below is just a sample
//Change values as needed in below connection
def driver = 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'
def connectionString = 'jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/db'
def user = 'your_user'
def password = 'secret'
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver(driver)
def sql = Sql.newInstance(connectionString, user, password, driver)
def query = 'select * from company'
sql.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the import statement for [`Sql`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) class, add the following import at the top of your script:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
```